# Uncaught ReferenceError: FileTransfer is not defined (using cordova 2.7.0)

Tags: android, cordova

I want to use FileTransfer to download a file from web server, code is as following:

```
  function downloadFile(url) {
     var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
     var uri = encodeURI(url);
     var filepath="www/download/";

     fileTransfer.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
        if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
          loadingStatus.setPercentage(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total);
        } else {
          loadingStatus.increment();
        }
     };

    fileTransfer.download(
      uri,
      filePath,
      function(entry) {
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
      },
      function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
      },
      false,
      {
        headers: {

        }
    }
  );
 }
```

when I run my app in simulator or real devide, all hit error message: Uncaught ReferenceError: FileTransfer is not defined.

I have included cordova.js, what is the reason for this error? thanks.

rgds
brent

Comment: In the beginning you set `filepath` but later on in .download() you use `filePath`. Is this just a copy/paste error?

Comment: yes, copy/paste error, should be "filepath".

Comment: error was occured at line of: "var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();".

Answer (score 2):

This plugin doesn't work from the browser, it will throw a “new FileTransfer is not defined” error. Use a real device to test.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install phonegap plugin:

```
$phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file.git
$phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file-transfer.git
```

If you already install, probably you need rebuild phonegap platforms:

```
$phonegap build android
```