# Cordova: Uncaught ReferenceError: FileTransfer is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, file-transfer

I would like to download a PDF file from a server and save it to the local storage of that device. 
To do that I have found the [cordova-plugin-file-transfer](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer).

running that piece of code:

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI("http://example.com/file.pdf");
var fileURL = "/Martin/Downloads/";

function openDocument() {
   fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    fileURL,
    function(entry) {
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    },
    false,
    {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
        }
    }
);
}
```

gives me that issue:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: FileTransfer is not defined

I have already removed all my platforms and reinstalled them. 
After that I have removed all my plugins and reinstalled them.

A similiar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442698/uncaught-referenceerror-filetransfer-is-not-defined-using-cordova-2-7-0) could not help me.

What else could I do ?

Comment: did you install the plugin? did you include the cordova.js in your index.html? are you waiting for the device ready event before trying to use the plugin?

Comment: Are you sure that you're accessing the plugin AFTER deviceReady was fired?

Comment: I installed the plugin with the following commands: cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file. After doing this I did: cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer. The command cordova plugin says that the plugins are installed. Cordova is also included in the header. How can I check if the plugin is used before the ready event?

Comment: it could be a problem with how you are testing it? are you running it in an emulator, browser, or building and deploying to a device etc?

Comment: the code I have given is inside of a onClick()-Function. So it is just possible to run it when I click the button. And to do this the device must be ready. Or do I miss something?

Comment: I run the App in the browser. Is that the problem for me?

Comment: When I implemented the FileTransfer plugin (for uploading images) I think it only worked for me when I deployed it to the device via PhoneGap Build because I dont think a browser could emulate the FileTransfer plugin

Comment: okay, I test it on a emulated Android device. I have figured out that the method is called correctly when the button gets pushed. After that the app does not run the whole code of FileTransfer but keeps giving me the issue: Uncaught ReferenceError: FileTransfer is not defined

Comment: Not all emulators will support the FileTransfer either see this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990816/phonegap-filetransfer-download-ripple-chrome 7 I know the link refers to the ripple emulator but it might not work for similar reasons

Comment: Now I have tested the app on a real Android device. There is the same Error message

Comment: in that case the error may be caused by something different and not what i thought. Just one last thing... did you build the app for android and then install it on your Android device? if you didnt it may not have included the FileTransfer plugin hence it causes the "is not defined" error

Comment: ok, now I have tried to build the app before I run it. It keeps going the same stupid behavior....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not the function but the init of the variables ran before device-ready was called.

here is the code that worked for me:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

var fileTransfer;
var uri;
var fileURL;

// use file transfer after onDeviceReady() was called         
function onDeviceReady() {
    fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    uri = encodeURI('http://example.com/file.pdf');
    fileURL = '/file.pdf';
}

function openDocument() {

   fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    fileURL,
    function(entry) {
        alert("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
        alert("download error source " + error.source);
    },
    false
);
}
```